# How to Specify directory to trigger code pipeline cdk?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I am using a cdk code pipeline and i would like to specify for it to only trigger if a  directory within the repo has changed.

```
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
    pipelineName: 'BackEndPipeline',
    synth: new CodeBuildStep('SynthStep', {
        input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(repo, 'master'),
        installCommands: [
            'npm install -g aws-cdk'
        ],
        commands: [
            'cd mydir',
            'ls',
            'npm install',
            'ls',
            'npm run build',
            'ls',
            'npx cdk synth'
        ],
        primaryOutputDirectory: 'mydir/cdk.out'
    })
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make CodePipeline watch a sepecific folder of CodeCommit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712657/how-to-make-codepipeline-watch-a-sepecific-folder-of-codecommit)

Comment: @gshpychka no, it does not answer my question and the vote to close my question is not helpful. Why are you like this?

Comment: Can you clarify? The question is the same as yours, and the answer is the same as well - it's not supported, you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a DIY job.  A CodePipeline is designed to run from start to finish, unconditionally. The trick is to trigger the pipeline only when there has been a relevant change.  You must replace the default trigger-on-every-change setup with manual triggering logic. For a `CodeCommit` repo:

(1) Turn off the pipeline's automatic trigger. Set the `trigger: codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitTrigger.NONE` prop in the [CodePipelineSource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipelineSource.html#static-codewbrcommitrepository-branch-props).

(2) Create an [EventBridge Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.Rule.html) to listen to your repo's commit events:

```js
const rule = new events.Rule(this, 'MyRule', {
  eventPattern: {
    source: ['aws.codecommit'],
    resources: ['arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:123456789012:my-repo'],
    detailType: ['CodeCommit Repository State Change'],
  },
});
```

(3) Add a Lambda as the [rule's target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events_targets.LambdaFunction.html).  The Lambda will receive the [referenceUpdated payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/monitoring-events.html#referenceUpdated) on a push to your repo.  The event payload contains the `commitId`, but not the changed files.  To get the file-level changes, your Lambda should call the [GetDifferences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_GetDifferences.html) API.  Your Lambda should then determine whether a relevant change has taken place.

(4) Manually trigger a pipeline excecution if required. Your Lambda should call the [StartPipelineExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_StartPipelineExecution.html) API or set the pipeline as a [custom Event target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events_targets.CodePipeline.html).

Comment: Thats what i initially suspected but was holding out hope wasnt the case. Thanks so much!